# Concerns about a stealthed port

Tags: networking

I run Ubuntu 14.04. Using the terminal, I did `netstat -taupen` to see what processes are running and I got this result:

```
Local Address        Foreign Address     State        User   Inode    PID/Program Name
192.168.1.3:54179    23.62.236.99:80     TIME_WAIT    0      0        -
```

Why is this ip connected to one of my ports? Also, ShieldsUp says port 54179 is stealthed, so what is going on?

Comment: That just looks like NAT (Network Address Translation) to me.. I could be wrong though

Comment: ^I do use NAT, so i guess. Also, every time I use netstat -taupen, the same result appears (User, Inode, PID) but with a different port and ip. Can it still be my NAT router? Sorry, I really am new to most of this.

Comment: You can get different IP addresses/ports if you have dynamic addressing. I can't really be sure exactly, it could even be your ISP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry. Its the address of the remote peer you are connected to. Your source port is 54179 and the destination port is 80. This might be due to browsing some site or any other program using it,  the `TIME_WAIT` indicates that the connection has been closed from your end but waiting for any delayed packets from the remote peer. The IP (23.62.236.99) belongs to [Akamai](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akamai_Technologies) so it should be a part of [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network).

Here is a line while running `netstat -taupen` in my computer:

```
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.5:55720      104.16.19.44:80         ESTABLISHED 1000       44338       2045/firefox
```

This suggests that i have an active connection to 104.16.19.44 (Askubuntu) and the source port is 55720 and the destination port is 80 via the program `firefox`.

Comment: That explains so much! But one last thing, is there any reason why the program name wasn't listed?

Comment: @Raffat: The process might be owned by root or any other user. Try `sudo netstat -taupen`